# What are some affordable hosting services for a webgis using?

Tags: web-gis

A friend and I have been building, for the first time, a webgis that enables queries and visualizations of data. Our work looks a bit like this:

http://www.communityindicators.net.au/files/SingleMap/atlas.html

We used PostgreSQL, Leaflet library, and PHP Zend Framework. These may be different from the website above, but I just use it to give a better sense of the design. We've been in a good shape and are likely to be able to upload the website on internet soon.

I want to know about some hosting services that support PostgresSQL as we have limited experience in this. Affordability is the preference since our work is more a demo at this stage.

Comment: Amazon is likely the best bet... DigitalOcean is another one.

Comment: There a are many similar questions around. Search for amazon instances or hosting provides in this site to find some. They all come with some nice answers for you to read on!

Comment: I've just updated my Meta answer at http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/4062/115 to give some advice on what you can do to seek answers to questions like this.  I'm going to rollback your question to its previous version, because both questions and answers should only contain problems and solutions rather than Meta requests - that particular one would have been fine as a comment .which you can do on your own question at any rep level.